Can legislation enacted post a hypothetical passing of CA Prop 33 address some of its opponents major concerns?
CA Prop 33 seems to be the one of most divisive item on California ballot this election. It would repeal Costa Hawkins which is California wide rent control law. Endorsements are all over the place with little predictability. I genuinely believe some folks on both sides of the issue genuinely want to address California's housing crisis.
Costa Hawkins blocks local governments from imposing rent control on certain types of housing. Chiefly on anything built after 1995.
Now, opinions aside, I want to ask about one specific point. Which is basically that without Costa Hawkins CA would be left with much less statewide rent control policy (AB 1482 likely remains in force). Opponents of Prop 33 will point out that local governments could impose extreme rent control legislation that would either purposely or unintentionally decrease the growth of housing supply be discouraging new development.
While that point can be debated, I am curious specifically about whether as a follow up to Prop 33 it is feasible for state legislators to follow up with laws of similar strength to Costa Hawkins to address these potential oversights in passing prop 33.
Specifically this addresses the concerns of those who are voting no because they hope for a later proposition that repeals costa Hawkins but replaces it with something better rather than leaving a vacuum.
For instance is it possible to expect that if there were a precipitous drop in new housing developments (due to local policies) state legislature could follow up with a new bill allowing rent control but with say a rolling date where rent control is limited.
If legislators would be able to create and pass such legislation what has stopped them from doing so while Costa Hawkins is still in effect?

Can you summarize Prop 33 in the question?

Yes. Added. It is a fairly involved law and I don't want to oversimplify.

Prop 33 is a regular proposition, not an amendment to the CA constitution, and it simply negates Costa Hawkins. So the CA Assembly could pass a new bill that addresses rent control issues.  Heck, they could even (technically) pass a bill that reinstates Costa Hawkins itself, though I doubt that would win them many favors.
The tension here is between housing affordability and revenue streams. Corporate landlords and state politicians like free market housing because it increases (respectively) profit margins and tax bases. However, free market housing puts stresses on low and fixed income people, increasing homelessness, food insecurity, and other ills that place burdens on local communities. Anti-33 people worry that that end of Costa Hawkins will see a spurt of strict local rent control measures that will chill new housing development and impact taxes; pro-33 people think that the status quo disincentivizes the construction of affordable housing in any case, so new housing development and stronger taxes won't solve the housing crisis, but may make it worse.
For me this is a no brainer: Costa Hawkins merely protects corporate landlords from accountability — another form of corporate welfare — and should have gone the way of the dodo ages ago. My 2¢…

Afterthought: I just realized that the section of the bill I mentioned in comments — “The state may not limit the right of any city, county, or city and county to maintain, enact, or expand residential rent control” — would necessarily preclude the Assembly from passing another Costa Hawkins type bill. Therefore the first paragraph above is incorrect (at least without a legal challenge to that section of 33). I've left the post intact for continuity, but please note the correction.

That's the way I feel but I am so torn given the AHF (a corporate landlord with a poor track record) is pouring millions into it. I have to hope a repealed prop 33 is going to end up differently then they think it will?

@CalebK: Well, one of the problems with invalidating any law is that it creates a legal vacuum, and there are lots of (…) people willing to take advantage of such vacuums. Reading the bill, I can't tell myself exactly what short-term advantages someone might gain from repealing CH, but I don't doubt that there are some. But maybe this fact-checking page will help.

@CalebK: I found this article on AHF's involvement. My guess their support of 33 has something to do with their non-profit status (Something most corporate landlords don't have).

@CalebK: The main area of concern I see is that 33 adds this line: “The state may not limit the right of any city, county, or city and county to maintain, enact, or expand residential rent control” see here. It's very broad language, and might have unforeseen consequences.  I mean, if the state later decides to pass a bill mandating a basic level of rent control, can a county refuse to do it? Doesn't feel like a deal-breaker to me, but I can see why some political actors might be skittish.

"However, free market housing puts stresses on low and fixed income people, increasing homelessness, food insecurity, and other ills that place burdens on local communities."
Free market is just another term for not having regulations. It's rather problematic to phrase the absence of something as causing issues, not least because the something can take many forms, and your framing obscures the difference between "it's theoretically possible for regulation to reduce these issues" versus "regulation in general addresses these issues" versus "all regulation reduces these issues".

It is basic, simple logic that decreasing homelessness necessarily means either increasing the amount of housing,  increasing the number of people living in each housing unit, and/or decreasing the population, and I don't see how rent control helps any of these.

"For me this is a no brainer: Costa Hawkins merely protects corporate landlords from accountability — another form of corporate welfare"
It's quite Orwellian to refer to not taking someone's property rights away as "corporate welfare". It sounds like you're just a socialist who considers any tolerance of private ownership of the means of production to be "corporate welfare".

Once again you show you have no willingness to engage in civil discussion, just insults.

@Acccumulation: sorry, but you're not the only person to make random insinuations about me recently, and I'm not in the mood to accept it graciously. Go write your own answer.
